# PhpStorm does not see Docker environment variables

Tags: docker, environment-variables, phpstorm

I tried to do different things with PhpStorm+Docker and every time I'm facing with one issue: PhpStorm does not see or cannot compile docker environment variables in some cases.

> 7.1-fpm/etc/php-fpm.ini

```
; This file is created automatically by the docker build

memory_limit = !PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT! ; Variable: PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT
```

At the moment attaching phpmd to PhpStorm it's claiming on memory limits (because most likely this variable isn't thrown into PhpStorm)

[image: phpstorm_docker_environment_variable_error]

As you can see on screenshot I tried to pass this variable into container directly in PhpStorm, but it wasn't successfully.

I replaced variable with the real value and here what we have:

```
; This file is created automatically by the docker build

memory_limit = 2048M
```

Rebuilt docker containers and tried again:

[image: phpstorm_docker_environment_variable_success]

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: Also, the way the question is put is wrong - it's not that PhpStorm doesn't see those environment variables. PhpStorm sets those variables and doesn't read them.
It's the PHP interpreter in the container that is responsible for reading vars. I explained why it failed to do so in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're using the wrong environment variables syntax in your php.ini, it's supposed to be `${PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT}` and not `!PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT! ; Variable: PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT`.

https://dracoblue.net/dev/use-environment-variables-for-php-ini-settings-in-docker/